# Get Current Activity Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, leadtools-sdk

I used Leadtools SDK for Barcode reader , when i try to get current activity it gives me null

This is my code

```
   Stream resourceStream = new MemoryStream();
        // Droid.MainActivity activity = Forms.Context as Droid.MainActivity;
        var activity = Android.App.Application.Context as Activity;

        int resId = activity.Resources.GetIdentifier("Datamatrix", "drawable", "com.companyname.UDOSE");
     resourceStream = activity.Resources.OpenRawResource(resId);
     var leadStream = LeadStream.Factory.FromStream(resourceStream);
     await ReadBarcode(leadStream);
```

activity always null , how can i solve this ?

Comment: still not .....

Comment: could work now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.define a global static Acitivity,in MainActivity :

```
public static MainActivity Instance;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);       
        Instance = this;
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```

when you use call `MainActivity.Instance`

2.use the **Current Activity Plugin**,you could refer to [Current Activity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin)

```
var activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
```

3.i suggest you use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to call the method which was defined in Droid project,like:

create a Interface in sharecode:

```
public interface IRead
{
    void Read();
}
```

then in Droid project create a class:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AndroidRead))]
namespace Demo.Droid
{
  class AndroidRead:IRead
   {
    public async void Read()
    {
        //here is your codes
        Stream resourceStream = new MemoryStream();
        // Droid.MainActivity activity = Forms.Context as Droid.MainActivity;
        var activity = MainActivity.Instance;

        int resId = activity.Resources.GetIdentifier("Datamatrix", "drawable", "com.companyname.UDOSE");
        resourceStream = activity.Resources.OpenRawResource(resId);
        var leadStream = LeadStream.Factory.FromStream(resourceStream);
        await ReadBarcode(leadStream);
    }
  }
 }
```

and call in page.xmal.cs like `DependencyService.Get<IRead>().Read();`

Comment: CurrentActivity cannot be called in shared project as it isn't compatible with .net standard

Comment: i think in your case,you should use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to call the barcode reader method in your shared code,and the method would be defined in Droid.

Comment: can you give me a sample for using dependecyservice in my case ?

Comment: @AmrKamal The above is the usage, you can refer to, according to your specific needs to modify

Answer (score 0):

In the Xamarin barcode demo shipped with version 20 of LEADTOOLS, the activity is obtained in MainPage.xaml.cs like this:

```
...
#elif __ANDROID__
   Stream resourceStream = new MemoryStream();
   var activity = Droid.MainActivity.Instance;
...
```

Please test with the demo and try this code out on your side and see if it is working.

Keep in mind that email support and online chat support services are both free, so if you have any questions related to our SDK or our demos, feel free to send them to support@leadtools.com

Comment: thank you but still has problem , Droid is missing what's the namespace ?

Comment: Did you build and run our demo without making any changes? Please send full details about what you're doing to our support email address and we will check it with you.

Comment: I think your sample doesn't work for .net standard it works only for shared project